# How do you unwrap the metadata from a ClojureScript object?

Tags: metadata, clojurescript

Adding meta data to an object returns a new object with the metadata attached:

```
(def plain-data [1 2 3])
(def decorated-data (with-meta plain-data {:url "http://stackoverflow.com"}))

;; returns false
(identical? plain-data decorated-data)
```

How do I recover the original `plain-data` from the `decorated-data`?

I'd like to do something like,

```
(def undecorated-data (with-meta decorated-data nil))

;; how can I make this return true?
(identical? plain-data undecorated-data)
```

Comment: I don't think this is possible. `with-meta` [returns](https://github.com/clojure/clojurescript/blob/master/src/cljs/cljs/core.cljs#L3336) a new object, which doesn't have a reference to the old object (just some of its members/properties).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding metadata doesn't wrap the value, it returns a clone of the value with metadata attached - there's no way to recover the original thing. However it's not clear why you would ever need to do that, use `=` if you need to check for equality.